# Can someone explain how while-loops with multiple conditions really work

Tags: python, while-loop

Can someone explain how this While-loop actually works, how this piece of code just end up to result: 3 and 1, and 4 and 0. How? Thanks.

```
i = 2
j = 2

while i < 4 or j > 2:
    i += 1
    j -= 1
    print(i, j)
```

Output:

```
3 1
4 0
```

Comment: Visualize it at http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display

Comment: It's important to understand, there is *only one condition*. The condition is a boolean expression. Are you asking how does that boolean expression work?

Comment: For this simple program you can go through it with pen and paper, line by line. Just remember (or write down) which values have i and j, how are the variables checked in the while-condition and how they change.

Answer (score 2):

On the first iteration, `i == 2` and `j == 2`. The condition `i < 4` is true, while `j > 2` is false. When you combine conditions with `or`, it's true if either of the conditions is true, so the combined condition is true and we go into the loop body.

Then it adds 1 to `i` and subtracts 1 from `j`, and prints the new values `3 1`.

On the next iteration `i < 4` is still true and `j > 2` is still false. Since one of them is true the `or` condition is true, so we go into the loop body.

Then it increments `i` and decrements `j`, and prints the new values `4 0`.

On the next iteration, `i < 4` is false and `j > 2` is false. Since both of the conditions are false the `or` condition is also false. So the loop stops.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need a proper IDE which includes a debugger. That way you can step through your code line by line and see what happens to each variable. I suggest [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/). They have a free community edition.

```
Line number     value of i    value of j    i < 4     j > 2     or of these
Program start   -/-           -/-           -/-
Line 1          2             0             -/-
Line 2          2             2             -/-
Line 4          2             2             True      False     True
Line 5          3             2             -/-
Line 6          3             1             -/-
Line 7          ^print        ^print
Line 4          3             1             True      False     True
Line 5          4             1             -/-
Line 6          4             0             -/-
Line 7          ^print        ^print
Line 4          4             0             False     False     False
End of program                                                  ^jump out of while loop
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were expecting to see “2 2” first you must place the print statements before the arithmetic operations. As you’ve formally asked it to, the loop applies the operations until neither clause of the ‘or’ is true, printing the result each time before moving onto the next step.

Answer (score 1):

I'm at home in my pyjamas, so I don't have the tools to check it out (and I'm too tired for theory), but here lies the big hairy monster:

They all give the same result as the op...

```
i = j = 2
while i < (4 or j) > 2:
    i += 1
    j -= 1
    print(i, j)

print('-'*5)

i = j = 2
while i < (4 or j > 2):
    i += 1
    j -= 1
    print(i, j)

print('-'*5)

i = j = 2
while (i < 4) or (j > 2): # Prefered way of doing things...
    i += 1
    j -= 1
    print(i, j)
```

Output:

```
3 1
4 0
-----
3 1
4 0
-----
3 1
4 0
```

So how does `i < 4 or j > 2` work?
Comparison operators have the priority and it is left to right. `i < 4`, `j > 2` are done first.

Then the logical operator `or` is applied.
See: [Operator precedence](https://www.techbeamers.com/python-operator-precedence-associativity/) (Don't trust what you read on the internet !)

Now there's another big hairy monster:

When using the `or` op, do we sill process the right operand when the left one is already True? Doesn't seem like it... But I don't have my tools to check if it behaves the same with simple values instead of functions.

```
def print_and_return(mah_var):
    print(mah_var)
    return mah_var

value = print_and_return(False) or print_and_return(True)
print('mah value!', value)

print('-'*5)

# Here, the right operand is ignored !
value = print_and_return(True) or print_and_return(False)
print('mah value!', value)

print('-'*5)

# Here, the comparison operand is ignored !
value = print_and_return(True) or print_and_return(True) > print_and_return(True)
print('mah value!', value)
```

Output:

```
False
True
mah value! True
-----
True
mah value! True
-----
True
mah value! True
```

So, first `i < 4` is processed. Then `or` is processed, which either returns the left operand value if true, else return the right operand value (trigger the processing of `i > 2`).